# Excel Addin HKLM vsto|vstolocal inactive

Tags: excel, wix, vsto

I create a install setup by Wix for all user. 
And I can load addin from file, not from ClickOne Cache then I nead registry value

Manifest :
file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/TargettyExcelAddIn/TargettyExcelAddIn.vsto|vstolocal
but addin go to inactive addins and dont work

but addin work (go to active addins) just in case :

Manifest :
file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/TargettyExcelAddIn/TargettyExcelAddIn.vsto

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me.

All resources must be local (copy local)
All binary library from project (.dll) must be in root folder of addin project (same location as vsto file)